# Allow None in required field using Python schematics

Tags: python, validation, schema

To validate data from an API, I've defined a schema using the `schematics` module. I want to ensure that all fields exist and contain a valid value. Setting `required=True` doesn't allow the value to be `None`.

Using `serialize_when_none` and leaving the type as not required (as suggested [here](https://github.com/schematics/schematics/issues/79#issuecomment-25130144)) doesn't check that the field exists.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: This seems to be more of a design issue rather than an issue with the library. If `None` is a valid value for a field then the field should not be required.

Comment: Perhaps `schematics` is not the right library to check for field existence, but since I'm using it for model validation, I just thought I could implement this extra functionality as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monkey patching the `BaseType` seems to be the only way to achieve this.

```
from schematics.exceptions import ConversionError
from schematics.undefined import Undefined
from schematics.types import BaseType

def check_required(self, value, context):
    if self.required and value is Undefined:
        if self.name is None or context and not context.partial:
            raise ConversionError(self.messages['required'])

BaseType.check_required = check_required
```